# Cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration in C Sharp

Tags: c#, constructor

This is the [Question](http://newthum.blogspot.com/2016/07/create-class-that-imitates-part-of.html) I am trying to solve in C Sharp.

I am getting an error:

> Error Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)

Can anyone help me to solve this or guide me to solve this?

```
namespace program
{
    public class Integer
    {
        private int intvar;
        public Integer()
        {
            intvar = 0;
        }
        public Integer(int x)
        {
            intvar = x;
        }
        public void display()
        {
            Console.Write(intvar);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        public void add(Integer x, Integer y)
        {
            intvar = x.intvar + y.intvar;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Integer a(5),b(45);
            Integer c;
            c.add(a,b);
            c.display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to create a new class instance you need to use `new` keyword. E.g. `Integer a = new Integer(5)`

Comment: @I.sypniewski Thanks to you, Eric & Alexander for help. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a new instance of a type, you have to invoke one of the constructors of that type using the new operator. For example:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Integer(5);
            var b = new Integer(45);
            var c = new Integer(); //result instance
            c.add(a, b);
            c.display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code alone does not provide a useful answer. Consider adding some explanation to expand your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create objects like that in C#. Im assuming you come from C++ where this syntax is possible.

In C# you have to create objects using new:

```
Integer foo = new Integer(45);
```

Comment: Correct, although similar syntax may soon be valid with [C#9 Target-typed new expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#target-typed-new-expressions).